# codigo de un Array

Tags: java

2) returns the value 0 instead of the correct value 1". Si alguien me pudiera explicar le porque, sería de gran ayuda.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public static int maxNumRepeated(Integer[] a, Integer elem)  {
```

}// de utils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola reorganize un poco tu logica ya que nucna estabas usando el booleano.

```
public static int maxNumRepeated(int[] a, int elem)  {
  int contador=0;    
  int contadorMax=0;
  boolean encontrado=false;

  if (a==null) {
      return 0;           
  }//de if    

  for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {     
      if (a[i]==elem) {
         contador++;

         if (a.length == i + 1)
            encontrado = true;
      }//de if
      else
      {
        if (contador > 0)
        {
          encontrado = true;
        }
        else
        {
         encontrado = false;
        }
      }

      if (encontrado)
      {
        contadorMax = Math.max(contador, contadorMax);
        contador = 0;
        encontrado = false;
      }
  }// de for      
  return contadorMax;  
}
```

Primero que nada si lo encuentra lo va contando aqui nos topamos con dos casos cuando solo hay un elementeo o cuando ya es el ultimo.

```
if (a.length == i + 1)
            encontrado = true;
```

para eso uso esa validación.

despues cuando detecta un cambio se valida el contador:

```
if (contador > 0)
        {
          encontrado = true;
        }
        else
        {
         encontrado = false;
        }
```

si es mayor a cero se marca como encontrado sino se marca como no encontrado.

Al final mediante la variable booleano ahora si aplico el max

```
if (encontrado)
      {
        contadorMax = Math.max(contador, contadorMax);
        contador = 0;
        encontrado = false;
      }
```

Espero se entendible las modificaciones. No soy experto me imagino que se debe de poder hacer de manera mas eficiente.

Comment: Muchas gracias :), si soy un desastre organizando mi código jaja

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo prueba con este for.

```
 for (int i=0;i<a.length ;i++) {
          if (a[i]==elem) {
              contador++;
          }
```

El error es porque pones `<=`, así que esta buscando en una posición que no existe recuerda que las posiciones son el tamaño - 1.

Comment: Se me ha solucionado el error anterior gracias, el problema ahora es este.                   the call Utils.maxNumRepeated([2],2) returns the value 0 instead of the correct value 1

Comment: No entiendo porque ya lo probé y funciona bien.

Comment: Debería regresar 1, pero regresa un 0...